# Gnome hangs up after wake up

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-17.04

Every time I press "login" when my laptop wakes up from the sleep state, Gnome GUI hang up for 30 secs to 5 minutes. No keyboard shortcuts are effective and the mouse pointer can still move, but I'm unable to click.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome-shell 3.24.1

Here is an error that is literally spamming my logs (I have something around 500 pages of it in less than 5 minutes). The timestamps corresponds to my problem. I used `journalctl --system` :

```
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[29510]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "panel-menu-keyboard-accelerator".
gnome-shell[29510]: clutter_layout_manager_get_child_meta: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_LAYOUT_MANAGER (manager)' failed
gnome-shell[29510]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
gnome-shell[29510]: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: Have you found anything with this?

Comment: No, sadly, I have another problem concerning my network that I should fix before this one. https://askubuntu.com/questions/883375/how-do-i-make-ifup-wlan0-return-immediately-if-no-dhcp-lease-can-be-obtained

Comment: Here it says the gnome-shell extension `Taskbar` is the problem. Uninstall it to fix it http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=124447

Comment: Another one says it's `TopIcon Plus` I tried both, and the result seems to be with a combination of these plus user themes. So disabling user themes solves everything.